# Setting up openai gym

Tags: neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, openai-gym

I've been given a task to set up an openai toy gym which can only be solved by an agent with memory. I've been given an example with two doors, and at time t = 0 I'm shown either 1 or -1. At t = 1 I can move to correct door and open it.

Does anyone know how I would go about starting out? I want to show that a2c or ppo can solve this using an lstm policy. How do I go about setting up environment, etc?

Answer (score 1):

To create a new environment in gym format, it should have the 5 functions mentioned in the gym.core file.

https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/e689f93a425d97489e590bba0a7d4518de0dcc03/gym/core.py#L11-L35

To lay this down in steps-

1. Define observation space and action space for your environment, preferably using gym.spaces module.
2. Write down the step function which performs agent's action and returns a 4 tuple containing - next set of observations from the environment , reward ,
   done - a boolean indicating whether the episode is over ,  and some extra info if you want.
3. Write a reset function for the environment to reinitialise the episode to a random start state and return a 4 tuple similar to step.

These functions are enough to be able to run an RL agent on your environment.
You can skip the render, seed and close functions if you want.

For the task you have defined,you can model the observation and action space using Discrete(2). 0 for first door and 1 for second door.

1. Reset would return in it's observation which door has the reward.
2. Then agent would choose either of the door - 0 or 1.
3. Then perform a environment step by calling step(action), which will return agent's reward and done flag as true - signifying that the episode is over.

Frankly, the problem you describe seems too simple to accomplish for any reinforcement learning algorithm, but I assume you have provided that as an example.
Remembering for longer horizons is usually harder.

You can read their documentation and toy environments to understand how to create one.